# Check if object exists in array MockMvcResultMatchers

Tags: java, spring, mockito, mockmvc

I'm writing tests using MockMvc in Spring. So I want to check if my response contains element I'm saving to repository, like so:

```java
    @Test
    void getScreeningsShouldReturn200() throws Exception {
        //given
        Screening screening = Screening.createScreeningWithRoom(Movie.createMovieWithTitle("Interstellar"), ZonedDateTime.now().plusMinutes(240), Room.createRoom());
        screeningRepository.save(screening);

        List<Screening> screeningList = new ArrayList<>();
        screeningList.add(screening);

        System.out.println(mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(screening));

        //TODO check below value if contains certain data
        //when
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                //then
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().string(mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(screeningList)))
                .andReturn();
    }
```

This way it works, but what if there would me many objects that I got from response, how would I find if this one exists inside array of many?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.rootObjectName.listName[0].fieldName").exists())
```

And as a personal advice, do two tests :

1. should_return_ok : `.andExpect(status().isOk())`
2. should_return_correct_data : `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.rootObjectName.listName[0].fieldName").value(<yourValue>))`

- if you don't use result of `.andReturn();` do implement it